# The database connection must be open to store files at GridFSStorage._handleFile

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ng-file-upload

I try to upload a file on local MongoDB server via a web application in the following:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Mongo URI
const mongoURI =
    'mongodb://localhost:27017/database'

// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

// Init gifs
let gfs;

conn.once('open', () => {
    // Init Stream
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection('uploads');
})


// Create storage engine

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database',
  file: (req, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          bucketName: 'uploads'
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    });
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

// @route GET /
// @desc Loads form

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
})

// @route POST /upload
//@desc upload file to DB
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
res.json({ file: req.file });
});

const port = 27017;
```

> app.listen(port, () => console.log('server started on port ${port}'));
>   but I get error: "The database connection must be open to store files
>       at GridFSStorage._handleFile (/Users/payam/Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage/lib/gridfs.js:341:17)
>       at /Users/payam/Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:144:17
>       at allowAll (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/multer/index.js:8:3)
>       at wrappedFileFilter (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/multer/index.js:44:7)
>       at Busboy. (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:114:7)
>       at Busboy.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Busboy.emit (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:38:33)
>       at PartStream. (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
>       at PartStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at HeaderParser. (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
>       at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at HeaderParser._finish (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:68:8)
>       at SBMH. (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:40:12)
>       at SBMH.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at SBMH._sbmh_feed (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:159:14)
>       at SBMH.push (/Users/.../Desktop/mongodb-uploads/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:56:14)".
>   can Any body help and tell me what is wrong with my code or with my
>   machine?

Answer (score 0):

all I needed to do was setting  useNewUrlParser: true for the Mongo URI :

```
// Create mongo connection
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

and for the port you can set to 5000, like below:

```
const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server started on port ${port}`));
```